# Correct way to nest form for join model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to nest a form for my Producttracklisting has_many through join model in my product show view. What is the correct way to do this? I'm getting various errors for my various failed attempts.
The models are as follows:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :producttracklistings
  has_many :tracks, :through => :producttracklistings
end

class Track < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :producttracklistings
  has_many :products, :through => :producttracklistings
end

class Producttracklisting < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :track
end
```

The form is as follows:

```
<%= form_for(@producttracklisting) do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :track_id %>
  <%= f.text_field :track_id %>
  <%= f.label :product_id %>
  <%= f.text_field :product_id %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

And i'm trying to bring this into product/show using:

```
 <%= render 'producttracklistings/form' %>
```

With all of the above I get a "undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class"

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're looking for is `accepts_nested_attributes` in combination with `fields_for`.
See this RailsCast [Part 1](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1) and [part 2](http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2) for a detailed tutorial.

PS:
I'd suggest to name your model `ProductTrackListing`, which results in a table named `product_track_listings`. This is far more readable and "the rails way"

Comment: Actually, i'm not sure that's what i'm after and I think I might have misused the word 'nested'. All i'm looking to do is bring in the Producttracklisting form to the product show view on it's own so I can associate tracks to that product. I basically plan to run a loop to display each track with an 'add to product' button. This works perfectly within the producttracklisting/new view.

Comment: Ah... I see. Ok, well the error "undefined method `model_name` for NilClass:Class" means that it can't resolve the model name by the given variable in the form_for call (ergo @producttracklisting is not set). So to use the same form you have to set this variable in your controller, i.e. with `@producttracklisting = @product.producttracklistings.build` or so...